# Issue - BigQuery Merge statement won't allow date partitioning - is now reading full table

Tags: merge, google-bigquery, partitioning, cost-management

We are trying to perform a merge 1 day of a date-partitioned table. We've followed google's recommended merge setup:

```sql
MERGE dataset.target T
USING (SELECT * FROM dataset.source WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = '2018-01-01') S
ON T.c1 = S.c1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 DELETE
```

We even put an extra piece of query into the when statement:

```
WHEN MATCHED and tgt._PARTITIONTIME = '2018-01-01' THEN
```

Running this query results in BQ querying our entire table instead of hitting only a single day.

Running the same query without the MERGE statement only hits 1 day of data as expected. We are wondering if anything changed on BQs side, since we made no changes to our datastructure whatsoever.

Cheers,